# Change UI language Skoda Citigo-E

Tags: skoda, citigo-e, infotainment-system

I have a Skoda Citigo E (VW E-Up basically). In the *infotainment* system, I've changed language to English without any problems, but I can't figure out how to change language in the driving computer interface in the dashboard - the messages show up in Norwegian even though language in the settings is set to English.

Does anyone know how to change language of this user interface as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the manual, see Driver Information System / Instrument Cluster Display / Operation where it says that if you press and hold the button on the end of the wiper control stalk, you get a menu. A short press of the same button up or down changes menu items. A press of the button on the bottom of the stalk confirms an item selection as OK.